# How can i draw shape with depth in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

How can i draw the 3d shape like i attached in image. wanted to make banner with just tiled slop. i tried in adobe illustrator but cant get the depth between the blocks. Please let me know how can i archive the same effect in attached image.[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to illustrate depth and I think the way you are trying to do it is with perspective.  You are close.  I can see what you were trying to do, but we would need to see them angle to the right as they go up if we are to believe they are going further into the image.

Here is an example I put together using your shapes.  These could have been touching but I would have had to mess with the angles a lot more rather than just letting the viewer imagine they are floating in space which requires less precision.

[image: Illusion of depth]

All modifications to these shapes was done with the free transform tool in illustrator.  The circle is just a circle, I added it to help the viewer relate to the depth I created.

This should help you see it a little better.  Neat concept you are exploring, keep working with it.  Please comment if you have any more specific needs to meet that you cant figure out.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I will try to follow your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Go to effect > Stylize > drop shadow

This will create the illusion of depth since there is a shadow.

You may need to adjust the settings.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up a gradient in the fill that will give the illusion of depth, and also a light source (the light source is not shown directly, but you knowing where it is will inform where the shadows should go). Adding shadows in the correct areas (based on light source) in the background will also help.

If that notched area is supposed to be a channel in the blue plane, you might have to fake that with an additional shape containing only a shadow fill (a gradient that goes from transparent to black to transparent, then adjust the transparency of the entire shape to give you the shadow you want) on top of the blue area to add shadows inside the notch.

Additionally, if the yellow, blue and red are arbitrarily chosen, you may want to think about swapping the yellow and red, since humans percieve stuff in the foreground is "brighter" than stuff in the background.

Answer (score 0):

If you must have the banner seen from straight on you are limited by creating the depth using width and height.

The illustration on the left is designed to show the banner with the red and yellow being parallel to us (like stairs), the one on the right shows how it would look if the red and yellow were slanting toward the viewer. It would be much easier to accomplish the task by also adding gradients to the shapes

[image]

Comment: Hi user364, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!